# proper way for filtering fields in req

Tags: node.js, express

What is the good practice to filter out fields for a specific route ?

I was thinking of making this middleware for endpoint A and B:

```
module.exports.filterA = function (req, res, next) {

// filter out unwanted fields for A in req.body    
    next();
};


module.exports.filterB = function (req, res, next) {

// filter out unwanted fields for B in req.body  

    next();
};
```

Then I can use the filters like follows to make sure endpoint A and B only let in their specific fields

```
router.post('/A', filterA, saveReqBodyToDatabase);
router.post('/B', filterB, saveReqBodyToDatabase);
```

My strategy is to cut out anything unwanted in req.body, and save the whole request to the database in the end, in order not to write a specific saving method for each route...

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
module.exports.filterA = function (req, res, next) {
    delete req.body.unwantedField1;
    delete req.body.unwantedField2;
    delete req.body.unwantedField3;
// filter out unwanted fields for A in req.body    
    next();
};
```

Or if you want to keep only one or two fields and remove the remainder:

```
module.exports.filterA = function (req, res, next) {
    var reqBodyOfOnlyDesiredAttributes = {
        attr1 : req.body.attr1,
        attr2 : req.body.attr2,
        attr3 : req.body.attr3
    }
    req.body = reqBodyOfOnlyDesiredAttributes;
    next();
};
```

Comment: no good, I only want to keep certain fields, and remove the rest

Comment: can you please try the second code snippet I just wrote?